# .jad file -> know the compiler version

Tags: java, blackberry

I have got one .jad file that is a blackberry application and I need to know the compiler version was used.

Have you got an ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***I have got one .jad file and i need to know the compiler version was used.***

Which compiler was used to compile the class files is usually not available in the jad file.

Here's a typical example of the content of such file:

```
MIDlet-1: HelloSuite, HelloSuite.png, HelloMIDlet
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 1144
MIDlet-Jar-URL: HelloSuite.jar
MIDlet-Name: HelloSuite
MIDlet-Vendor: Unknown
MIDlet-Version: 1.0
Manifest-Version: 1.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.0
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.jad` does not contain any compiled Java code, it's only meta-data.

Unless the compiler version is noted in it (check it, it's plain text), there's no way to find that information.